# Incompatible pointers types sending in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, nsmutablearray

I have created two classes, one for StockHoldings, and the other Portfolio (an array). I created the values in main and am trying to add the created stock values into the portfolio, but when I do it I get "incompatible pointer types sending..."

This is what I have in main:

```
Portfolio *thisPortfolio = [[Portfolio alloc] init];

[thisPortfolio addPortfolioObject:[stockOne valueInDollars]];
```

Even if I just try and put an integer in place of [stockOne valueInDollars] which is a method of that calculates a stock's value based off instance variables in stockholding, then I get "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'Portfolio'..."

This is what I have in the Portfolio.h file:

```
@interface Portfolio : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *myPortfolio;
}

- (void)addPortfolioObject:(Portfolio *)a;
```

And this is what I have in the Portolfio.m file:

```
- (void)addPortfolioObject:(Portfolio *)a
{
    // Is assets nil?
    if (!myPortfolio) {

        // Create the array
        myPortfolio = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    [myPortfolio addObject:a];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is stockOne? what does `valueInDollars` return?

Comment: I added in more details above. Thanks.

Comment: if u want to add integer to an NSArray use : - (void)addPortfolioObject:(int)a
NSNumber* objVal = [NSNumber numberWithInt:a];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface of `Portfolio`, indeed you declare the signature of `addPortfolioObject` such that a `Portfolio` object is expected, not an integer. The signature will have to change to `(void)addPortfolioObject:(int)a` both in the interface and the implemention. The latter will have to wrap `a` in an `NSNumber` using `numberWithInt` because `NSArray` can only store `NSObjects` while `int` instead is a base type.